# How Do I Create One-to-One Relationship

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

What is the best way to create a one-to-one relationship between these two tables?

Here is the ER Diagram

[image]

Here is the SQL statement for the Athlete table but I'm still not sure how to create the DressingRoom table

```
CREATE TABLE Athlete
(
StudentID   INT NOT NULL,
FirstName   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
LastName    VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Gender      VARCHAR(9),
Eligibility VARCHAR(15),
CONSTRAINT AthletePK PRIMARY KEY (StudentID),
CONSTRAINT GenderCheck CHECK (Gender IN ('Male', 'Female')),
CONSTRAINT EligibilityCheck Check (Eligibility IN ('Eligible', 'NotEligible'))
);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired, results, and the table layouts as text *in the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like a 1-N relationship, where each athlete may have 0 to N lockers.

Here are typical DDL statements for this schema:

```
create table athlete (
    studentID int primary key,
    firstName varchar(50),
    lastName varchar(50),
    gender varchar(5),
    eligibility varchar(50)
);

create table dressingRoom (
    lockerNumber int,
    studentID int references athlete(studentID),
    lockerBuilding varchar(50),
    primary key (studentID, lockerNumber)
);
```

The important thing is that you want a foreign key on `dressingRoom(studentID )` that references `athlete(studentID)`.

If you want a 1-1 relationship, meaning that each student may only have one locker, then you can use `lockerNumber` as a primary key, and set a `unique` constraint on `studentId` (or the other way around):

```
create table dressingRoom (
    lockerNumber int primary key,
    studentID int references athlete(studentID) unique,
    lockerBuilding varchar(50),
);
```

Note that in that case, it makes little sense to create two tables. You can store the `lockerNumber` directly in `athelete`, with a `unique` constraint:

```
create table athlete (
    studentID int primary key,
    firstName varchar(50),
    lastName varchar(50),
    gender varchar(5),
    eligibility varchar(50),
    lockerNumber int unique
);
```

Comment: My professor is asking me to have 1-to-1 relationship where each student must have 1 locker. I'm trying to do that but I'm still confused by the unique key I must create.